# Escape sequence for SSH keystroke

Tags: c#

I want to send an ssh command using

```
 SshCommand x = cSSH.RunCommand("ssh command");
```

The command I want to send is "Control C". should I declare it or I can send it directly ? Can you please provide me with the shh command format of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\x03` to pass `CTRL-C` to the server. Read more on [ASCII Table](http://www.unix-manuals.com/refs/misc/ascii-table.html).